# Getting Windows games to play on PlayOnLinux

Tags: games

I used Play on Linux and Starcraft II as a test to see if I can play my library of games on Linux... I'm having a bunch of problems.. just when it looks like it I'll work I get another runtime C library error, and it stops...

Is there something I can just press and something fix this for me?

Comment: I recommend editing your question to describe the problems you're having specifically. Also, please include the full and exact text of all error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Visual C++ runtime libraries:

1. 2010 = http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A-475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe
2. 2008 = http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/8/5D8C65CB-C849-4025-8E95-C3966CAFD8AE/vcredist_x86.exe
3. 2005 = http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A-475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe

Check [this link](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/install-starcraft-2-on-linux-ubuntu-with-wine-.html) for StarCraft II on Ubuntu

Comment: I launch Starcraft II from the /PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/SC2_WoL/drive_c/Program Files directory...  the first thing that happens is the searching for patch dialogue comes up after awhile I get a Star craft II Launcher dialogue .. "Failed to run a required program Agent).  Wat one minute and try again...  At the bottom it says "Error code: BLZPTS00007"

Comment: I downloaded all of the items above, but problem still occuring...  Question, does Ubunta play Microsoft games has anyone ever got Starcraft II to play ??  is it really involved, or simple, so far it doesn't seem to be simple.